# SoapUI WADL authentication

Tags: rest, authentication, soapui, wadl

In order to view wadl file from my server in an internet browser it's necessary to authenticate.
I would like to test my webservices using soapui however when I add new project and in initial wadl/wsdl I enter path to wadl file on my server the project is created but operations are not listed. How to authenticate user and password in order to get valid wadl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a SOAPUI version 4.6.4, there is a bug importing authentication protected wsdl which provokes that the basic credentials prompt is not showed up. You can see more details [here](http://forum.soapui.org/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=22818).

There is a maintenance build for SOAPUI PRO where this bug is solved: http://www.soapui.org/Downloads/soapui-pro-nightly-builds.html.

Comment: Yes, I'm using a SOAPUI version 4.6.4, however I don't want to buy SOAPUI PRO. I will try downloading 4.6.3 and see if it works.